# How do you get a country from language?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

If I have a browser in English (US) then the header returns to me `en_US`. I am getting a US country code here. But for example, when I use Japanese and download the header, I only receive it `ja`. There is no country code given, e.g.`JP`. Is it possible to get the country code somehow based on the language?

Comment: So what is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  The language being sent back is not, by any means, a good indicator of where the user is.

Comment: What would the country code for "en" be?

Comment: You usually can't (at least not reliably). Several countries have the same language. Some countries have several languages. There is a reason why `Locale` in Java is defined having **both** language and a qualifier code.

Comment: Not understanding. Languages such as English or Arabic are used in many countries, their code looks like this ```en-CA``` ```en-IE``` ```en-NZ``` ```ar-DZ``` ```ar-BH``` ```ar-EG```. However, such languages as Danish or Polish are used only by one country. That's why their code looks like this ```da``` ```pl```. And that's why if I receive only the language then I would like to get the country code, eg for the Danish language it would be ```DK```.

Comment: Browsers don't always include the country code, even when the language is spoken in multiple countries. You're just as likely to get `en` or `ar` without the contry code. Not to mention that the language code is literally what language the user prefers, not where their location is (e.g. I have the browser set to en-US even though I'm in Europe.)

Comment: Some languages have slight differences depending on the country. For example, US English uses color,and  honor,where UK English uses colour and honour. Also, some words mean diffefrent things in US English than they do in UK English.What part of a car is the hood? What is a torch?

Comment: Well, so what?......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and build something that works for your use case.

The following is a quick example to showcase how to use Locale to achieve the desired behavior. The code still can be improved.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public final class CountriesList {

    private final Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    private static CountriesList instance = null;

    private CountriesList() {
        init();
    }

    // static method to create instance of Singleton class
    public static CountriesList getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CountriesList();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountriesList list = CountriesList.getInstance();
        System.out.println(list.getCounryCode("da"));
        System.out.println(list.getLanguage("ja"));
        System.out.println(list.getCounryName("en-US"));
        System.out.println(list.get("ar-MA"));
    }

    public String getCounryCode(String code) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(code);
        if ("".equals(locale.getCountry())) {
            locale = new Locale(code, map.get(code));
        }
        return locale.getCountry();
    }

    public String getCounryName(String code) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(code);
        if ("".equals(locale.getCountry())) {
            locale = new Locale(code, map.get(code));
        }

        return locale.getDisplayCountry();
    }

    public String getLanguage(String code) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(code);
        if ("".equals(locale.getCountry())) {
            locale = new Locale(code, map.get(code));
        }

        return locale.getDisplayLanguage();
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(code);
        if ("".equals(locale.getCountry())) {
            locale = new Locale(code, map.get(code));
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Language = ").append(locale.getDisplayLanguage());
        sb.append(", Country = ").append(locale.getDisplayCountry());
        sb.append(", Language (Country) = ").append(locale.getDisplayName());
        sb.append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // create map with languages and corresponding countries
    public void init() {
        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        for (Locale locale : locales) {
            if ((locale.getDisplayCountry() != null) && (!"".equals(locale.getDisplayCountry()))) {
                map.put(locale.getLanguage(), locale.getCountry());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// DK
// Japanese
// United States
// Language = Arabic, Country = Morocco, Language (Country) = Arabic (Morocco)
```

I hope this helps!